# Retrieving query results from inside radio buttons

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms

I am trying to echo out or print out the query results from this radio button:

```
<input type="radio" name="Query" value="SELECT employees.name FROM employees, department WHERE employees.department_deptID=department.deptID AND department.departName="Information Technology""> List all employees in a particular department (Information Technology).<br />
```

The code I currently am using is this:

```
if ($_POST['submit'] == "submit" && isset($_POST['Query'])){
$query = $_POST['Query'];
$result = mysql_query($query);
print $query;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    foreach($row as $cname => $cvalue){
        print "$cname: $cvalue\t";
    }
    print "\r\n";
}
    }
```

Along with a few other radio buttons I also have a submit button to initiate the action:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what is the problem here ?

Comment: I'm trying to get the data from my table to display once the submit button is clicked

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\1059\SQLstatements.php on line 46
Could not successfully run query (SELECT employees.name FROM employees, department WHERE employees.department_deptID=department.deptID AND department.departName=Information Technology) from DB: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Technology' at line 1-------That is my error message

Answer (score 0):

Try the following block:

```
<input type="radio" name="Query" value="SELECT employees.name FROM employees, department WHERE employees.department_deptID=department.deptID AND department.departName='Information Technology'"> List all employees in a particular department (Information Technology).<br />
```

I have replaced the `"` with `'` at `department.departName='Information Technology'`

**Note: This whole logic looks bad idea to me. You are passing the query from the browser which results in high risk. Also use mysqli_* functions and stop using mysql_* functions**

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Information' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\1059\SQLstatements.php on line 32----- that is the error message I get when doing as instructed.

Comment: The above radio button:    <input type="radio" name="Query" value="SELECT employees.name FROM employees, department WHERE employees.department_deptID=department.deptID AND department.departName='Information Technology'"> List all employees in a particular department (Information Technology).<br />

Comment: I mean what is written on the code on `C:\xampp\htdocs\1059\SQLstatements.php on line 32`